# Connect to OracleDriver

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I have this code :

```
    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");       
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/test", "user", "password");
```

What configurations do i need to make in my system/administrative tools for this to connect to my database ?

I have Oracle 11g installed and running in my system.

Comment: what do you mean ? Can you clarify ?

Comment: Is ojdbc6.jar in your classpath?

Comment: Above config is enough to connect to db.

Comment: Connecting to MySQL is of course not going to work with the Oracle driver. Please check the documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/toc.htm

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. You are loading the Oracle driver, yet you use a JDBC URL that is for MySQL. Those are two totally different things. Which DBMS are you actually using? Everything you need to know is documented in the manual for Oracle: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/toc.htm and for MySQL: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you must add `ojdbc6.jar` to library folder and try again to connect to database,I think your url is false.oracle connection url is like that `jdbc:oracle:thin:@" your ip ":1521:`

Comment: adding the jar file has resolved the initial exception. Now i am getting "TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor"

Comment: you must add SID after port 1521 I don't know your SID

Answer (score 2):

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/test", "user", "password");
```

This is the mysql connection URL and you are trying for oracle.

Try this way

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
    "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:db","username","password");
```

Comment: what is thin and is 1521 the default port?

Comment: @qualtar yes 1521 is the default port number

Comment: @qualtar thin is client

Comment: are u sure i dont need to make any changes in my administrative tools. I used to create a odbc bridge when working with jdbc odbc.

Comment: @Kalathoki : i have not created thin anywhere. Where do i need to create it?

Comment: @qualtar You need to download ojdbc.jar http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-112010-090769.html is the link. And save in your lib folder

Answer (score 0):

hope you are confused with the `odbc` connection. ODBC is microsoft's interface to connect to a datasource. we use `sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver` for getting connection.

you do not require odbc connections since you have the `driver`(jar) for the particular db server (mysql in your case).